# Encode filename spacebars for browser (CS)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button that starts uploading a filename that has Spaces.

Firefox fails to use this name, its OK for IE.

How to encode spaces to underlines with csharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The String.Replace(char, char) method, thus:

```
string filename = "This is an example";

string encodedFilename = filename.Replace(' ', '_');

Console.WriteLine(encodedFilename);
```

Produces "This_is_an_example".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String safeFileName = fileName.Replace(" ", "_");
```